# How to get parse errors from gtk+3 builder?

Tags: c, linux, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

I'm learning C language with GTK to build GUIs.
I have a problem, I start to pogramming a sofware very simple, I compile without errors but don't show a window and don't show errors and don't show warnings neigther.
I think that problem is on the interfaz file but i don't know how to get parse errors from that file in gtk with c language. 
This is my code

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    GtkBuilder *programa;
    GObject *ventana;


    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    programa = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(programa, "interfaz.ui", NULL);

    ventana = gtk_builder_get_object(programa, "ventana");

    gtk_main();
    return 0;    
}
```

and this is the content the gui file

```
<interface>
    <object id="ventana" class="GtkWindow">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="title">BackLight's Keyboard</property>
        <property name="border-width">10</property>
        <property name="width">100</property>
        <property name="height">100</property>
        <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window_destroy" swapped="no"/>

        <child>
            <object id="cajaVentana" class="GtkGrid" >
                <property name="visible">True</property>

                <child>
                    <object id="Imagen" class="GtkImage" >
                        <property name="file">backlighticon.jpg</property>
                        <packing>
                            <property name="left-attach">0</property>
                            <property name="top-attach">1</property>
                            <property name="width">2</property>
                        </packing>                       

                    </object>    
                </child>

                <packing>
                </packing>
            </object>
        </child>
    </object>
</interface>
```

Answer (score 1):

You never call `gtk_widget_show_all()` add this before `gtk_main()`

```
gtk_widget_show_all(GTK_WIDGET(ventana));
```

Actually, you call `gtk_builder_get_object()` but you do nothing with that variable, so that line of code is completely unecessary, unless you add what y suggest.

Comment: Try `GtkWidget *ventana = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);` instead of the gtkbuilder, does it work?

Comment: Don't work neighter. I want know how to show the errors with GLib GErrors. Thanks for help me, Sorry my bad Engish

Comment: @CarlosAguirre Yo sé español mejor que inglés, pero aquí no se permite. Hay funciones para imprimir los errors de glib, busca en google.

Answer (score 1):

The last parameter of `gtk_builder_add_from_file()` is a GError object that will receive error information if there is an error; the return value of `gtk_builder_add_from_file()` indicates whether an error occurred. Check the GLib documentation for more details. (iharob's answer is probably correct, but knowing how to deal with errors is useful as well.)

Comment: Hi, i read the documentation and I don't know how to use the GErrror I don't understant. You should give me a example

Answer (score 0):

Declare a

```
GError *error=NULL;
```

in the line

```
gtk_builder_add_from_file(programa, "interfaz.ui", NULL);
```

change for

```
gtk_builder_add_from_file(programa, "interfaz.ui", &error);
```

and show errors with

```
fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", error->message);
```